# Failed to load project in Play framework

Tags: java, mysql, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

I am trying to learn the Play Framework using Java. The Play version is 2.4 and using Java 8. I am trying to learn to perform MySQL operations from Play Java. I used the `activator ui` to download the template `computer-database-java`. However, i get an error saying

```
(*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#sbt-fork-run-plugin;2.3.7: not found
Failed to load project.
```

How can i resolve this? Also, any tutorials for connecting and performing MySQL operations using Play...The official document is not that good.

Comment: That template is using 2.3.7, not 2.4 of Play. What changes did you make to the template? I've just tried it with 2.3.7, ran ok. Did you run "./activator" in the directory?

Comment: I'm having the same issue @bjfletcher, I have play version 2.4 at the moment that I got from the activator bundle. Is there a way to upgrade the template to use 2.4? Doesn't seem like a breaking upgrade

Comment: @ObjectiveTruth Did you just get it and replaced 2.3.7 to 2.4.1 in the plugins.sbt?

Comment: @bjfletcher, I ended up just not using the template. I downloaded the Activator package and used the webapp to make a new project seed. However, it seems all of them have that issue except the official ones with stars beside them. I dunno if the update just happened, but they all ask for 2.3.7 but running Activator initially downloaded 2.4

Answer (score 7):

goto `computer-database-java\project` folder, edit both `plugins.sbt` and `play-fork-run.sbt` files, change 2.3.7 to 2.3.8 and it worked for me.

It seems the 2.3.7 was removed from the repositories.

Comment: This resolves the problem in quite a few Activator examples and seeds that rely on 2.3.7. Anyone have any idea why 2.3.7 was simply removed, seems like a bad idea – since it breaks all those old seeds and examples! Would love to know the backstory...